# TPT to TPH discriminator column issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, discriminator, tph

I had a class:

`public class A { }`

Now, I change it to abstract and create two implementations:

`public abstract class A { }`

`public class First : A { }`

`public class Second : A { }`

EF 6 completed the update and created the `Discriminator` column. But if there was existing data in table, the `Discriminator` value is not set.

How can I update/set `Discriminator` value for already existing data with EF 6 Code First?

Comment: Usually, a delete and recreation is needed to properly sync newly complex `EF Core` models with the Database entities. Did you try a [migration](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-migration.aspx) in your case ?

Comment: No. I have automigrations. Possibily I wouldn't delete and recreate the database when changing TPT to TPH